# conda.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object

Tags: linux, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, miniconda, anaconda3

I want to install miniconda on my remote linux desktop and I am able to access it only in command-line mode.
I just tried,

```
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and I am getting this error :

```
/root/miniconda3/conda.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object
```

I am not able to understand the issue.
Please guide me.

P.S.: I also tried TMPDIR but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following commands:

```
mkdir ~/TMP
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
TMPDIR=~/TMP bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -p /usr/local/miniconda3
```